# How to fix the error "package not found! : system.web" in the Ring programming language?

Tags: scripting-language

While trying the next program from the Ring programming language documentation

```
Load "weblib.ring"
Import System.Web
WebPage()
{
    Text("Hello World!")
}
```

I get the error message

```
"Error in package name, Package not found! : system.web in file     C:\Ring\weblib\index.ring"
```

The example use "System.Web" but I don't find it in Ring directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the WebLib 1.0 source code from the Ring website (http://ring-lang.net) then copy weblib.ring to your application folder, The weblib.ring contains the System.Web package.

Comment: thanks for your response and your time. No big issue anyway I